# Looking for a web-based log collection/display application

Tags: database, web-services, web-applications, logging

A project I'm working on currently involves using a disparate set of technologies, including .NET, PHP, Asterisk and bash scripting. Each of the applications in use produces some logging; technical logging for administrators and user logging. The technical logging is easy, all logs are written to disk as text files.

For the user logging, I'd like a central portal where messages can be viewed, filtered and perhaps reported on.

Essentially, I'm looking for a web based application that will accept a number of log sources (including web services and syslog at a minimum), allow the logs to be stored, displayed and filtered in a web UI and ideally have the possibility of triggering events such as email or SMS.

I'm about to embark on writing this application; before I do, I want to make sure that I'm not reinventing the wheel. Any pointers/recommendation?

EDIT

I've found [Exceptioneer](http://exceptioneer.com/) and [Hoptoad](https://www.hoptoadapp.com/pages/home) - both of which look promising - are there any other tools like this (ideally open source) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Loggly](http://www.loggly.com/product/) seems to most closely meet my requirements. I also found [Errbit](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2010/08/24/introducing-errbit.html) (open source HopToad-alike), [LogStash](http://code.google.com/p/logstash/) (looks a bit immature for now) and [GrayLog2](http://www.graylog2.org/).

I suspect I'll give Loggly and Hoptoad a go.

Answer (score 0):

[Logverse](http://www.logverse.com) might be in the ballpark of what you are looking for.

Comment: Logverse (the linked-to product) seems pretty useful and cool, but I think that it should be made a little more obvious that the service is not free. The subscription pricing plans are not revealed until you create an account and set up a subscription. They run anywhere from $10 to $20 per month (or an annual price). There are limitations on the size of logs and number of entries per day, as well as limitations on users.

Comment: Actually, there is a link on the first inner page (the "What is it?" page) that has pricing information. You don't have to create an account to see that information.

Comment: -1 just because their webpage took over 10 seconds to load for me (a little worrying for a cloud infrastructure service).